# python extracting item from xml

Tags: python, xml

i want to read an xml-file in python, it looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <project name = "proj1">
        <design name = "des1">
            <param>para1</param>
        </design>
        <design name = "des2">
            <param>para4</param>
        </design>
    </project>
    <project name = "proj2">
        <design name = "des2">
            <param>para2</param>
        </design>
    </project><project name = "proj3">
        <design name = "des3">
            <param>para3</param>
        </design>
    </project>
</xml>
```

I'd like to use xml.etree.ElementTree

I can read all Projects like this

```
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for child in root:
        print child.get("name")
```

but how do i get a specific item, lets say param in des2 in proj1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for `etree` for a list (with examples) of everything you can do to traverste the DOM and retrieve the data. You might want to read about [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) as well, in case you're not familiar with it (even though this module [does not fully support it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), you can use a subset of it to easily retrieve some elements). For your specific example, it would be:

```
root.find('project[@name="proj1"]/design[@name="des2"]/param').text
```

Comment: interesting, but what if I have more than one param? Can i use root.findall('project[@name="proj1"]/design[@name="des2"]/param') and iterate through that?

Comment: @Yui sure! That will return a list of elements, so you can use them just like you were doing in `for child in root`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd use lxml rather than the native python ETree code. This way you can use XPath, which makes manipulating xml much easier.

For example the code to get the element you're asking for would be:

```
param = root.xpath(/project[@name="proj1"]/design[@name="des2"]/param/Text()')
```

UPDATE: Looks like ETree supports a subset of the full XPath, so it will suffice for your requirements as pointed out by @mgibsonbr